# FTP UPLOAD FILE Laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to send an excel file who was created when i refresh the page. I used the package https://github.com/harishanchu/Laravel-FTP

When i run the code bellow i get an exception like :

> pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I don't want to pick up a file in the storage because the system that i made will run the daily query everyday and send the file via FTP ! so i can't know the path before the file was created.

Hope someone could help me on this ! thanks a lot in advance

here the full code :

```
$licencies = Licencies::where('lb_assurance' , '=' , 'Lafont')
        ->leftJoin('activite_licencie' , 'activite_licencie.id' , '=' , 'licencies.activite_licencie_id')
        ->leftJoin('saisons' , 'saisons.id' , '=' , 'licencies.saison_id')
        ->leftJoin('pays' , 'pays.id' , '=' , 'licencies.pays_naissance_id')
        ->leftJoin('type_licence' , 'type_licence.id' , '=' , 'licencies.type_licence_id')
        ->leftJoin('structures' , 'structures.id' , '=' , 'licencies.structure_id')
        ->leftJoin('civilite' , 'civilite.id' , '=' , 'licencies.civilite_id')
        ->leftJoin('catg_licence' , 'catg_licence.id' , '=' , 'licencies.catg_licence_id')
        ->select('num_licence' , 'civilite.lb_civilite' , 'lb_nom' , 'lb_prenom' , 'dt_naissance' , 'pays.fr' ,'activite_licencie.lb_activite' , 'catg_licence.lb_catg_lic' , 'type_licence.lb_type' ,'saisons.lb_saison', 'lb_surclassement' ,  'structures.nom_structure' , 'lb_assurance' , 'cd_dept_naissance' , 'lb_adresse' , 'tel_fix_licencie' , 'tel_port_licencie' , 'adresse_email')
        ->whereRaw('DATE(licencies.created_at) = CURRENT_DATE')
        ->get();

    $licencies->map(function($licencie) {

        $licencie['dt_naissance'] =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($licencie['dt_naissance'])->format('d/m/Y');
        //$licencie['created_at'] =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($licencie['created_at'])->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        return $licencie;

    });

    $date = Carbon::now('Europe/Paris')->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');

    $file = Excel::create('Assurance Lafont - Saisie des Licences FFRXIII le : ' . $date . '' , function($excel) use ($licencies) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($licencies);

        });

    });

    $directory = 'mydirectory' ;

    $ftp = FTP::connection()->uploadFile($file, $directory);

    dd($ftp);
```